# Can we see logs(info) of an ionic app in PROD?

Tags: ionic-framework, logging, mobile

I search a way to **see logs** of an ionic application in **PROD.** I'm talking about **logs info** and not logs error (I know there are some platform which capture errors like Sentry). The goal is to have more data to solve issue i get in prod.

Thanks you.

Comment: you could use firebase crash reports so errors can be sent to ur firebase, or there was an intel crash reporter and that is the plugin from ionic side "https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-center-crashes", i think these are what ur looking for...

Comment: I'm talking aout logs INFO and not log errors. I want to see them not only when there is an error which is thrown